# How to cut a csv file through linux knowing a row may contain double quotes with comma inside it and delimeter as comma

Tags: linux, csv

Csv file contains the following data :-

```
"Name","Age","City"
"John, Doe",30,"New York"
"Alice","25","Los Angeles"
"Bob","28","Chicago"
```

the required column can be any random value.
with the following linux command when tried to get column 1, got result as following:-

```
NL1402:~$ awk -F'","' '{print $1}' data.csv
"Name
"John, Doe",30,"New York"
"Alice
"Bob
```

My desired output was :

```
"Name"
"John, Doe"
"Alice"
"Bob"
```

when tried to get column 3 got this as a result:

```
awk -F'","' '{print $3}' srijan.csv
City"

Los Angeles"
Chicago"
```

but require this :

```
"City"
"New York"
"Los Angeles"
"Chicago"
```

need help in linux command for the above to cut csv file knowing some attributes can have double quotes with comma inside it and the csv has a delimeter comma

Comment: `csvcut` from the csvkit package is your friend.

Comment: `awk 'BEGIN {FPAT = "([^,]*)|(\"[^\"]+\")"; OFS=","} {print $1}' file`

Answer (score 0):

If you use a full CSV aware tool as [Miller](https://miller.readthedocs.io/en/6.9.0/installing-miller/), it's easy. Run

```
mlr -N --csv cut -f 1 input.csv
```

to get

```
Name
"John, Doe"
Alice
Bob
```

The same for 3 (`mlr -N --csv cut -f 3 input.csv`).

If you want to use field name the syntax is slightly different:

```
mlr --csv cut -f Name input.csv
```